# I am not getting any notification ringtone when my whatsapp is open and I am chatting to a different person. So I am not getting the ringtone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am not getting the Notification ringtone when my Whatsapp chat box is open. While I am chatting with one friend, if the other friend message me, I am not getting ring voice.

Answer (score 1):

Open Whatsapp > Settings > Notification > Check whether **Conversation tones** is checked (allowed)